# Profile details not returning correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

So I'm not getting the correct results returned for the user profile. Say I got to

```
http://localhost/scott
```

And when I'd look at the name for example I'd see `Tony` as a name. Even though the URL doesn't look like

```
 http://localhost/tony
```

Heres how I query

```
//Get link username
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$final =  parse_url($actual_link, PHP_URL_PATH);
$username = str_replace('/','',$final);
```

Here's how I get the user info

```
//Get user info
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$stmt2->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();
$return = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And here's how I get the results. `$return['name'];` is an example. I might get the profile picture and other info. I think this has something to do with my sessions, but I don't see any noticeable issues on the other files. Any ideas? No errors either.

Comment: what does `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` print when visiting http://localhost/tony?

Comment: It returns `/tony` @puredevotion

Comment: And I've also tried a direct query like this `$stmt2->bindValue(':username', 'scott', PDO::PARAM_STR);` @puredevotion

Comment: and the direct query doesn't work either? just to be sure, the query in mysql/phpmyadmin does work and return the correct result? (it's unlikely that it's session related). Just to be clear, it fetches all the correct fields, except for the username?

Comment: Its getting all the results. Also when I do `var_dumb` on result I get the correct results. So `var_dump($return)` would return the array with the correct URL user  @puredevotion The only issue seems to be actually _displaying_ them.

Comment: Its only when I do say `$return['name']` I get the incorrect result.

Comment: OK. clear your cache in the browser, check again. can you post the php code for displaying? If you get the correct results from the DB, and only displaying goes wrong, then the issue is not in the query/DB-connection